# Best config for my Microsoft Designer Bluetooth keyboard and mouse

Tags: bluetooth

**Problems**

- Intermittant nature
- The mouse will often hang (won't move)
- The kb will often not type
- Sometimes, the keys get saved up and come out later all at once, and
  sometimes they never come out
- The mouse seems to have difficulty travelling to the top left of the
  screen. Equipment

---

- ThinkStation P910 Tower,
- Windows 10 Professional operating system,
- microsoft designer keyboard,
- microsoft designer mouse,

both mouse and keyboard are connected via bluetooth dongle.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken

Wired keyboard and wired mouse work great.

Question

What would be a good first choice for a fix I can try that won't hurt anything (update a driver...where?)?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the drivers would be among the first steps to try out (start by locating the keyboard, the mouse and the Bluetooth dongle in the Device Manager and clicking on "Update Driver"). Other troubleshooting steps may include:

- putting fresh batteries (or fully charging) your wireless devices
- reducing the distance between the dongle and the devices (if this is a USB dongle plugged at the back, use an extension cable to bring it to front)
- disabling WiFi networking (especially if WiFi and BT share the antenna)
- plugging an external antenna if your dongle has a socket for it
- using a different BT dongle

Answer (score 0):

What class USB port are they plugged into?

I have had similar issues, with microsoft keyboard and mouse, when the bluetooth dongle reciever, was plugged into a USB 3.0 port. Plugging into 2.0 solved my issue.

Another issue may be distance from the reciever, which casues choppiness due to loss of signal integrity.